# How to find one day previous and one day after for given date which are comma separated or given in range in Pandas df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({         
      'dates': [ '10-Mar-22,9-Apr-22', '5-Jan-22 to 1-Mar-22,10-Mar-22 to 7-May-22']})
```

```
    dates

0   10-Mar-22,9-Apr-22

1   5-Jan-22 to 1-Mar-22,10-Mar-22 to 7-May-22
```

required output for row 1
Previous day1 next day1 previous day2 next day2 (there are multiple dates in the column Restricted dates)

```
  dates                       PD1          ND1      PD2       ND2

0   10-Mar-22,9-Apr-22           09-Mar-22   1-Mar-22  8-Apr-22   10-Apr-22

1   5-Jan-22 to 1-Mar-22,      4-Jan-22    2-Mar-22    9-mar-22    8-may-22
```

10-Mar-22 to 7-May-22

required output for row 2

to understand row 2  better i am explaining here

Input:5-Jan-22 to 1-Mar-22,10-Mar-22 to 7-May-22

PD1:4-Jan-22, ND1: 2-Mar-22,PD2: 9-Mar-22,ND2: 8-May-22

There could be multiple date range(contain multiple to)

Comment: Can there be more than 2 values/ranges in `dates`?

Comment: yes.in row 1 also multiple comma separated and in row two also multiple ranges. for eg. 2/2/21 to 5/3/21,7/3/21 to 6/6/21,8/7/21 to 10/8/21 ....

Comment: What would be your desired output in that scenario?

Comment: previous day and next day of each comma separated value and previous day and next day of each range

Comment: So you expect 3 sets of columns (PD1, ND1, PD2, ND2, PD3, ND3) for 3 inputs?

Comment: @Nick :Yes,  I expect n time input the n times PD and ND